# user authentication for all pages in wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to to have a wordpress website for authorized users only. I was thinking to add custom php code to my theme's header file that checks if a specific user is authorized to access the page and if not users are redirected to a custom login page. I am also thinking of adding a new table to my database for user information. Is there a plugin that does that for me? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Do you have FTP access to the site's folder?

Answer (score 0):

Apply basic authentication to the site's folder where the wordpress site is.

Create a .htaccess file in the folder like this (but using your own path and username):

```
AuthUserFile /home/YOURACCOUNT/public_html/wordpress/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Authentication"
AuthType Basic
<LIMIT POST GET>
require valid-user YOURUSERNAME
</LIMIT>
```

Then create a .htpasswd file like this:

```
YOURUSERNAME:YOURPASSWORD_AS_MD5_ENCRYPTION
```

To convert your password to MD5 encryption go here:

http://hash.online-convert.com/apache-htpasswd

Comment: But I wanted to have a custom login page and maybe even a registration page for users. This way only one user can access the website if I understood your solution correctly. Basically, basic authentication was not something I had in mind

Comment: Well then create a user database, and then create a username and password form with a database lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with some nasty hacking I was able to work it out. 
In my theme's header.php file I added the following lines of code to the top:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
  session_start();
}
if (!$_SESSION['authenticated']) {
  header('Location: '.get_site_url().'/login.php');
}
```

I created a custom login.php file in my project's root folder containing a simple login form, posting its data to another custom file "webservice.php" with the following lines of code:

```
//webservice.php
<?php
    if(session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }
    $username = $_POST['username'] ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $password = $_POST['password'] ? $_POST['password'] : '';

    if ($password && $username) {
        $response = file_get_contents("http://example.com/api/Accounts?username=".$username."&password=".$password);
        $json = json_decode($response);

        if ($json->{'Status'} == "Success") {
            $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
            echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://example.com/\">";
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['authenticated'] = false;
            echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://example.com/login.php?incorrect=yes\">";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://example.com/\">";
    }
```

Yet, in another custom file(logout.php) I only unset my session variable:

```
<?php
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
if ($_SESSION['authenticated']) {
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = false;
    echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://example.com/\">";
}
?>
```

I would love to know my solution's disadvantages...

Answer (score -1):

Based on your additional comments try a plugin with wordpress to make the work easy on you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/user-registration

Comment: This looks promising. I'll take a look at it and get back to you.